# Exerecise 14 error in "Learn Python the hard way"

Tags: python

So I've ran my code several time, I have it word for word and line for line in the book yet theres an error that keeps popping up:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ex14.py", line 25, in <module>
    ''' (likes, computer, house)
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

I had to change the input once to "PS C:\Users\J> python  ex14.py YourNameHere" for the exercise, but this is when the error occurs. I do not understand why the string is not callable. My full code is below:

```
from sys import argv

script, user_name, = argv

prompt = '>'

print "Hi %s, I'm the %s script." % (script, user_name)
print "I'd like to ask you a few questions."
print "Do you like me %s?" % user_name
likes = raw_input (prompt)

print "What kind of computer do you have?"
computer = raw_input (prompt)

print "Where do you live %r?" %user_name 
house = raw_input (prompt)

print '''
ALright, so you said %r about liking me.
You live in %r. Not sure where that is.
And you have a %r computer. Nice.
''' (likes, computer, house)
```

Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: Please edit your question with appropriate formatting, i.e. show what is code and what is not- this makes is clearer for everybody to see what is wrong and to answer your question.

Answer (score 2):

```
 print ''' ALright, so you said %r about liking me. You live in %r. Not sure where that is. And you have a %r computer. Nice. ''' (likes, computer, house)
```

In this line here (which is the issue) you're missing a the "%", which should go as such:

```
print ''' ALright, so you said %r about liking me. You live in %r. Not sure where that is. And you have a %r computer. Nice. ''' % (likes, computer, house)
```